# How do I flatten this complex json using PySpark?

Tags: json, pyspark, azure-synapse, flatten, spark-notebook

**Background:** I am using Azure Synapase to pipe data from an API to a json file. I am than using a PySpark Notebook to flatten that complex json so that I can load data into a SQL Database.

**Comments** I have spent hours trying to modify this PySpark Code to flatten this appropriately and have had zero luck, any help would be appreciated.

**Structure of Complex JSON**

[image: Structure of JSON File]

**My PySpark Code**

```
    from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

dfGetReportData = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").option("mode", "PERMISSIVE").json('xxxxxxxxxxxxx')
#dfGetReportData.printSchema()
#dfGetReportData.show()

dfReportData = dfGetReportData.select("response.requestId", "response.code",explode("response.result.reportData").alias("reportData"))
#dfData.printSchema()
#dfData.show()

dfRentRoll = dfReportData.select(explode("reportData.current_residents").alias("current_residents"))
#dfRentRoll.printSchema()

dfCurrent_Residents = dfRentRoll.select("current_residents.property_name",
       "current_residents.property",
        "current_residents.lookup_code",
        "current_residents.bldg_unit",
        "current_residents.bldg",
        "current_residents.unit",
        "current_residents.floorplan_name",
        "current_residents.unit_type",
        "current_residents.space_option",
        "current_residents.sqft",
        "current_residents.unit_status",
        "current_residents.unit_occupancy_type",
        col("current_residents.unit_address").getItem(0).alias("unit_address"),
        "current_residents.bed", 
        "current_residents.bath",
        "current_residents.resident_name",
        "current_residents.phone_number",
        "current_residents.email",
        "current_residents.occupants",
        "current_residents.original_lease_start",
        "current_residents.lease_id",
        "current_residents.lease_status",
        "current_residents.lease_occupancy_type",
        "current_residents.move_in_date",
        "current_residents.lease_start_date",
        "current_residents.lease_end_date",
        "current_residents.previous_lease_end_date",
        "current_residents.move_out_date",
        "current_residents.lease_term_name",
        "current_residents.lease_term",
        "current_residents.contract_length_months",
        "current_residents.occupied_length_months",
        "current_residents.market_rent"
                )
#dfCurrent_Residents.show()
#dfCurrent_Residents.printSchema()
dfCurrent_Residents.write.mode('overwrite').parquet("abfss://entrata@steussynapseprod001.dfs.core.windows.net/Silver/entities/Reporting/RentRoll")
```

**Error Message**

```
AnalysisException                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [17], line 12
      8 dfReportData = dfGetReportData.select("response.requestId", "response.code",explode("response.result.reportData").alias("reportData"))
      9 #dfData.printSchema()
     10 #dfData.show()
---> 12 dfRentRoll = dfReportData.select(explode("reportData.current_residents").alias("current_residents"))
     13 #dfRentRoll.printSchema()
     15 dfCurrent_Residents = dfRentRoll.select("current_residents.property_name",
     16        "current_residents.property",
     17         "current_residents.lookup_code",
   (...)
     91         "current_residents.military_rank_band"
     92                 )

File /opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py:2023, in DataFrame.select(self, *cols)
   2002 def select(self, *cols: "ColumnOrName") -> "DataFrame":  # type: ignore[misc]
   2003     """Projects a set of expressions and returns a new :class:`DataFrame`.
   2004 
   2005     .. versionadded:: 1.3.0
   (...)
   2021     [Row(name='Alice', age=12), Row(name='Bob', age=15)]
   2022     """
-> 2023     jdf = self._jdf.select(self._jcols(*cols))
   2024     return DataFrame(jdf, self.sparkSession)

File ~/cluster-env/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py:1321, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1315 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1316     self.command_header +\
   1317     args_command +\
   1318     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1320 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1321 return_value = get_return_value(
   1322     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1324 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1325     temp_arg._detach()

File /opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py:196, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
    192 converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)
    193 if not isinstance(converted, UnknownException):
    194     # Hide where the exception came from that shows a non-Pythonic
    195     # JVM exception message.
--> 196     raise converted from None
    197 else:
    198     raise

AnalysisException: Can't extract value from reportData#191: need struct type but got string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your getting this error is because some of the records inside `reportData` consists strings.
So it takes all of the record type as string type, if you try to extract it you will get error.

[image]

Due to second record which is having a string `Done`
all other are stored with type string.

So, to avoid this you can load this data using function `from_json` providing a standard schema for the column `reportData` schema.

Below is the standard schema created on `reportData`

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode,flatten,col,from_json
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField,ArrayType,StringType,IntegerType

schema = json_schema = spark.read.json(dfReportData.select("reportData").rdd.map(lambda row: row.reportData)).schema

dfReportData = dfReportData.withColumn("json_ex",from_json(col('reportData'),schema)).drop('reportData')
dfRentRoll = dfReportData.select(explode("json_ex.current_residents").alias("current_residents"))
display(dfRentRoll)
```

[image]

Now you can use your further code for `dfCurrent_Residents` and write to parquet.

**Note**: Some of the records in `reportData` becomes null if they doesn't match the standard schema, check them properly and use.

Comment: Very much appreciated. That was spot on and makes sense. I was literarily stumped.